# When using dualboot, can Windows 10 access files on my Ubuntu encrypted partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows, encryption

If I am using dual boot (GRUB2) from 1 physical hard disk, would be Windows 10 and/or the software on the Windows 10 partition (including malware and viruses) be able to access the my encrypted Ubuntu partion?

Do I need to encrypt the bootloader location too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters Windows can't even mount an ext file system by default in the first place. so the chances of windows accessing your encrypted Ubuntu partition is imposable unless you use a problem like [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/).

Your drive is encrypted what makes imposable to access without providing a password.

Windows virus have no affect what so ever on a Linux Operating system what so ever so there is no need to worry.

Comment: You are wrong, there are Windows programs that can access ext file systems. For example http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/

Comment: @JohnDoerthy didn't know that Intel now but you have encrypted your drive what makes it imposable to access without providing a password.

Comment: well, I hope that it's true and if I encrypt the root, (home) and swap partition it will be OK and the Linux part will be safe from the Windows "eyes" ;)